# aligning the axes labels in 3d plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, axis-labels

I plot the mesh data with the following matlab commands

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(-10:0.1:10, -10:0.1:10);
z = exp(-x.^2 - y.^2);
mesh(x, y, z);
xlabel('time variable');
ylabel('space variable');
zlabel('wave');
```

You will see that no matter how to rotate the axes,  the x and y label are always aligned horizontally. Is there any way to make it align with the x axis and y axis separately while I rotating the axes?

Answer (score 1):

There has been a submission to align axes labels with the figure axis [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27450-align-axes-labels-in-3d-plot/content/axesLabelsAlign3D.m).

Comment: This only works for `axis equal` which is of little use for most 3D plots.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the `rotation` property of each label:

```
set(get(gca,'xlabel'),'rotation',angle); %where angle is in degrees
```