# Parallel Labels on 3D axes plot with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axes

How can I turn the label of the axes on a 3D plot from this:

(Labels "perpendicular" to the axes)

[image]

To this:
(Labels "parallel" to the axes)

[image]
Perhaps, with the `Y label` in this case turned of `90 degree`.

I simply use `ax.set_xlabel('X axis')`, and respective, for each of the three axis, but the labels result perpendicular, and occupy a substantial part of the plot.

I was reading [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669503/aligning-the-axes-labels-in-3d-plot-in-matlab), but it is actually not answered, and the `get` module I don't know where it comes from (I receive error if I try that solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following as the best workaround:

```
ax.zaxis.set_rotate_label(False) # To disable automatic label rotation

ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_xlabel('X', rotation=-90)
ax.set_zlabel('Z', rotation=90)
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918380/rotating-axes-label-text-in-3d-matplotlib).

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you imported `axes3d` module. Because it seems from looking at the [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) examples, that the default behaviour of `axes3d` is to have labels "perpendicular", as on your first plot. But the module `Axes3D` have default labels to be "parallel" to the axes, as on your second plot.

As for discussion you linked, it applies to matplab and not to matplotlib.

Here is a code that should work for you:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

points = np.random.rand(3, 40)

ax.scatter(points[0], points[1], points[2])

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You mean `Axes3D` is different from `axes3d`? Btw, I have imported `Axes3D` as well.

Comment: @Py-ser: I don't know about the inner workings, but as I saw from examples provided in their gallery, it seems that they behave differently. Have you tried the above code?

Comment: @Py-ser Sorry, but I can't help you there, since I don't see your code.

Comment: This works for me. @Py-ser maybe providing a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question would help?